# Assassin's Creed Revelations hangs on Windows 10?

Tags: technical-issues, assassins-creed-revelations, windows-10

I am trying to play *Assassin's Creed: Revelations*, installed from Uplay, running on Windows 10, but it hangs before the story mode begins (on the screen with the main character on some unspecified background).

If I look at Task Manager I can see that one core is fully used. How can I fix it or where can I find help?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Uplay in-game overlay? That seems to cause problems for other people. I've also seen that deleting `systemdetection.dll` from the game folder has helped people for whom the game was crashing.

Comment: @pushasha, I just tried both of these and sadly it didn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

According to the Steam page for this game, it is not compatible for Windows 10, and there's no telling if it will ever be. Ubisoft likely doesn't care that much.

Screenshot from Assassin's Creed Revelations Steam page:

[image: AC-Revelations Steam Requirements]

Perhaps try running the application in compatibility mode for Windows 7. To do so, find the AC-Revelations folder in your Steamapps location, then:

- Right click the executable for the game, and select Properties
- Find the compatibility tab, select "Change Settings for All Users"
- Check "Run this program in Compatibility Mode"
- Choose Windows 7 SP1 from the Drop down

And try it again. If this does not work, @pushasha's comments may work. Otherwise, there may simply be no hope, as compatibility to Windows 10 is tricky.

Comment: I tried compatibility mode and @pushasha's comments but neither worked :(. Annoying, because the previous games worked fine under Windows 8 (before I upgraded). This one was also hanging under Windows 8.

Comment: @Grzenio Without being a game coder or part of the team that developed the game, there's really no telling why.